# Why touchMajor and touchMinor are the same? How to configure?

Tags: android, motionevent

My question is, why touchMajor and touchMinor are the same? According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getTouchMajor%28int%29), I suppose that touchMajor and touchMinor should be different. Do I need to some configuration?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        double x = event.getX();
        double y = event.getY();

        double pressure = event.getPressure();
        double size = event.getSize();
        double touchMajor = event.getTouchMajor();
        double touchMinor = event.getTouchMinor();
        double toolMajor = event.getToolMajor();
        double toolMinor = event.getToolMinor();
        double orientation = event.getOrientation();

        Log.i("touchevent", "\t" + x + "\t" + y + "\t" + pressure + "\t" + 
        size + "\t" + toolMajor + "\t" + toolMinor + "\t" + touchMajor + "\t" + touchMinor + "\t" + orientation);

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is likely that your hardware just does not support the differentiation. While the SDK allows for this, the controller of your touchscreen might not and thus just returns the same value for both. Different vendors might implement this in a different fashion. Have you tried it with a Google phone?

Coming to think of it, I think this might not easily be possible with capacitive touch screens. But, if the screen you are using uses FTIR, the properties have indeed different values.

http://www.ghettocode.net/projects/FTIR/Intro

Comment: My project group and I have attempted this on several devices. Two of which was Asus Nexus 7 (tablet) and LG Nexus 5 (phone). None of which provided orientation or different major an minor axes of an ellipse.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050028/android-finger-detection-orientation-and-ellipse