# Android finger detection - Orientation and ellipse

Tags: android, motionevent

I've been looking for a way to detect the finger orientation together with a simplification of the touch area in the form of an ellipse, when using a mobile touch device. I choose Android rather than iOS since I found three usefull methods ([getTouchMajor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getToolMajor%28int%29), [getTouchMinor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getToolMinor%28int%29), and [getOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getOrientation%28int%29)) in the Android reference for the [MotionEvent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).
But I've tried to implement these three methods in my app, and sadly they does not return the wanted values. The orientation stays at 0, no matter what, while the getTouchMajor and getTouchMinor is exactly the same each time.

So my question is: Am I doing somethign wrong or is these methods just not implemented yet?

(I've tried the functions on several different devices including: Nexus 5, Nexus 7, and HTC One)

Comment: Bump!
It is very troubling that these methods was introduced to the API at level 9, now being level 19, making it 10 levels old, roughly 3 years ago.
And no requirements for the hardware to support these features have been made, leaving developers questioning the possibilities within the medium.

Comment: It's been about two years since I've used these, but they have definitely worked for me in the past on a number of devices. Have you also tried using `getHistoricalOrientation`, `getHistoricalTouchMajor`, etc. It might also be worth trying `getSize` and `getHistoricalSize`.

Comment: Dane, do you remember which devices you have used? And did you get the correct values?
Since I wrote the post, I managed to get my hands on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, which actually gave different numbers for `getTouchMajor` and `getTouchMinor`. But unfortunally it turned out that `major` was just `minor` multiplied by three, at all times.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't recall the devices. At that time, where I worked had several hundred different Android devices. I just gave it a try on my Moto X, and got major/minor numbers that reflected the touch size. But major/minor were always equal. And orientation was always 0.  So that seems like a common scenario. I would imagine something that ships with a stylus (like Galaxy Note), would return better values.

Comment: I'm using a Galaxy Note Pro 12.2 from 2014 and it still gives orientation -pi always and major = 3 * minor, and it seems to change just in discrete steps of approx 0.5, they should remove this from the API if after 10 versions of the API no manufacturer is giving correct info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we work together I know you know this answer, but I just wanted to put it up such that fellow users of Stackoverflow can have it as well.

We have found suggestive comments that maybe the touch screen drivers for most devices do not provide this data to the system.

We originally tested: Samsung Galaxy S2, HTC One, Nexus 5 (by LG) and Nexus 7 (by Asus), Samsung Galaxy Tap 3.

As opposed to the others the Samsung Galaxy Tap 3, gave different values for getTouchMajor() and getTouchMinor(), but this relationship was seen getTouchMajor() = getTouchMinor() * 3, and getOrientation() was always 0, as with all the other devices.

About 2 months later we discovered that the **Google Nexus 10** can show an ellipse with a direction line, when you activate *Input: Pointer Location* under developer settings.

The initial conclusion was that most devices do not support, getTouchMajor(), getTouchMinor(). or getOrientation(), Which could be a limitation of the capacitative touch screens.
But seeing the **Nexus 10**, and the tracking of the ellipse and orientation gives hope for new interaction design.

It indicates to me that some devices do deliver on getTouchMinor and getTouchMajor as well as orientation. (or historical versions of the same functions). 
I have not had the chance to code anything for the device myself but it seems plausible.