# MotionEvent getOrientation() returning orientation of screen instead of orientation of contact?

Tags: java, android, touchscreen

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the `MotionEvent`'s `getOrientation()` function, but from reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getOrientation(int)), my understanding is that it should return the angle between the major axis of the ellipse formed by the point of contact and the vertical axis. However, it seems to be reporting the orientation of the screen instead.

Here, I've just overridden the `onTouchEvent` for `MainActivity`. There's a few `TextView` that change when an `ActionMove` event fires, and they display the length of the major axis, minor axis, and supposedly the orientation of the ellipse.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            orientation.setText(String.valueOf(event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_ORIENTATION)));
            touchMajor.setText(String.valueOf(event.getToolMajor(pointerId)));
            touchMinor.setText(String.valueOf(event.getToolMinor(pointerId)));
            break;

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

TouchMajor and Minor work fine, but my problem is that the orientation doesn't change with contact. Instead, when I rotate the screen such that the screen orientation changes:

- 90 degrees CW = -PI/2
- Upright = 0.0
- 90 degrees CCW = PI/2

And the reported orientation is ever only one of these three.

So my question is, how can I properly grab the orientation of the contact area? I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S6 on Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that even at this late date, most devices do not properly support getOriention(). See [Android finger detection - Orientation and ellipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050028/android-finger-detection-orientation-and-ellipse)

Comment: Yeah, I came across this post while searching for an answer. Since it was posted in 2014, I was hoping that things have changed, but I suppose since the phone I've been testing with is similarly old, I'll have to see if I can get my hands on a newer one.