# getTouchMajor() is not precise: I can not get real value about the touch area length

Tags: java, android

I want to show the length and width of the touch area when I use a finger to touch the screen on an android phone. After trying the method of getTouchMajor(), it could only provide me with discrete numbers from [55, 99, 123, 187, 219, 250 etc.] instead of a continuous change when the touch area changes.

On the contrary, the method getX() and getY() are very sensitive and could provide continuous values of the touch location. But the getTouchMajor() and getTouchMinor couldn't do that.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    float touchWidth = event.getTouchMajor();
    float touchLength = event.getTouchMinor();


    TextView textX = findViewById(R.id.touch_x);
    TextView textY = findViewById(R.id.touch_y);
    TextView textWidth = findViewById(R.id.touch_width);
    TextView textLength = findViewById(R.id.touch_length);


    textX.setText(Float.toString(touchX));
    textY.setText(Float.toString(touchY));
    textWidth.setText(Float.toString(touchWidth));
    textLength.setText(Float.toString(touchLength));

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I expected to see a continuous change of the values of touch width and touch length on the phone when I touch the screen.

Another small problem I met: the outputted length and width are the same but I thought they should be different because the document said the touch area is an eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the hardware I used doesn't perfectly support the methods. BTW, I got inspired by Camilla in this link: [Android finger detection - Orientation and ellipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050028/android-finger-detection-orientation-and-ellipse).

Then I tested my program on 4 android devices: Nexus 5, Galaxy Note 8, Galaxy Tab S and Pixel 3 XL.

Results:

1. Galaxy Note 8, Galaxy Tab S and Pixel 3 XL could differentiate the major axis from the minor axis.
2. All 4 devices couldn't return meaningful value by getOrientation() method.
3. Galaxy Note 8 has the best precision, then Galaxy Tab S and Pixel 3 XL, Nexus 5 has poor precision.